Does the isotropy definition of a perfect fluid imply no heat conduction?
Weinberg defines a perfect fluid (Chapter 2, Section 10) as one where each fluid element appears isotropic in a reference frame moving with that element.
From the definition of the stress-energy tensor for a fluid, it's clear that:

$T^{00}$ is the energy density $ρ$, which is greater than the rest mass density if the particles have kinetic energy in the rest frame.

$T^{0k}$ is the energy current. This is nonzero if heat is flowing into or out of the fluid element.

$T^{j0}$ is the $j$-momentum density. The fluid element itself has zero total momentum density; however, if heat is flowing into or out of the fluid element, then the directional movement of energy will result in a net momentum density.

$T^{jk}$ is the $j$-momentum current. The assumption of isotropy means that $T^{jk} = pδ_{jk}$, where $p$ is the isotropic pressure in the rest frame. This implies the absence of any shear forces between fluid elements. (If $A$ is the area of a small patch of the surface $x^k= \text{constant}$ bounding a fluid element, and $\bf{F}$ the force on $A$, then $T^{jk} = F^j/A$. Hence, $T^{jk}≠0$ for $j≠k$ would imply a shear force.)


QUESTION: It seems you could satisfy Weinberg's assumption of isotropy while heat is moving into or out of the fluid element in a spherically symmetric fashion. Then, $T^{0k}$ and $T^{j0}$ would not be zero. Shouldn't Weinberg add the assumption of no heat conduction within the fluid?

I think isotropy does imply no heat conduction. If there were isotropic heat conduction into or out of a small fluid element at $x$, then there would have to be non-isotropic heat conduction into or out of an adjacent fluid element near $x$.
